# How to re-design my relational model if there will be NULLs in one column?

Tags: database-design, erd, null, database-diagrams

I'm trying to build database which allow me store job postings from scraped websites and now I'm in phase of creating a relational model. Getting straight to the point I want to know how should I re-design  my relational model if I know one of my linking table's column (`FK3 level_id`) will contain NULLs. And the model:
[image]

In brief:

1. Every job posting has title and source website (`Jobs` table).
2. Sometimes job posting contains information about additional skills. Their names I store in `Additional skill` table
3. `Additional skill` may be required or may be not required (`isRequired column`).
4. Additional skill may or may not contain information about its level (I store level names in `Level` table).
5. Because job posting may contain information about 0 or 1 or many additonal skills and each one of them may have its own level I associated everything in linking table (`Addiotional_skill-Level-Jobs`
   )

`Overall_required_level` linking table is not important in this question.

Because we know that job posting may contain several `Additional skill` and not every `Additonal skill` may contain information about its own `Level` so there will be nulls in `level_id` column in `Additional_skill-Level-Jobs` linking table. To be honest they are not as bad as they look but I'd like to know how could I improve my relational model if I know with certainty that one of the column will be having NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

Whether to allow NULL values or not is a religious topic. If you decide that it's OK to have nulls, you'll need to add a synthetic primary key to the link table, because the combination of `job_id`, `skill_id`, and nullable `level_id` cannot uniquely identify a row.

Comment: Hah, I read the same thing somewhere on stackoverflow :P. Ok two things: why should I add synthetic key? I'm asking because I've read somewhere that linking tables don't necessarily need such one. And second: let's say I want to do something with this problematic column. What should I do? I mean how should I re-organize my model?